# Inverse of 3-by-3 matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

[image: Taken from khan academy]
Hi, so this question is taken straight from khan academy help exercises, i know how to do it dynamically meaning using the determinant and the adjugate how i was trying to do it using guass bla bla way with help of RREF but i somehow never managed to find the inverse. 
my second question would be is there anyway that i can find the whether or not the matrix is invertable without trying to find the determinant i mean also using Gauss bla bla way
i use the word bla bla because i dont know what it is actually called :p

Comment: You probably want [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix).

Comment: Well you could try writing down the nine equations in nine unknowns and solve the old fashioned hard way.

Comment: @PedroM. yea its a little bit of guassian eli. and RREF too but if someone knows how to do it and shows me it'd be much appreciated

Comment: You want to find the bla bla RREF of $(D,I)$, giving you bla bla $(I,D^{-1})$ if $D^{-1}$ exists. If you can't find bla bla $(I,D^{-1})$, the matrix is not invertible or how is it actually called.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel hahah what? you over used bla bla in your comment made it hard for me to follow along

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Gauss-Jordan elimination:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
0&1&2   &1&0&0\\
1&0&1   &0&1&0\\
0&1&0   &0&0&1
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1&0&1   &0&1&0\\
0&1&0   &0&0&1\\
0&1&2   &1&0&0\\
\end{array}\right] \to\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1&0&1   &0&1&0\\
0&1&0   &0&0&1\\
0&0&2   &1&0&-1\\
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1&0&1   &0&1&0\\
0&1&0   &0&0&1\\
0&0&1   &1/2&0&-1/2\\
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1&0&0   &-1/2&1&1/2\\
0&1&0   &0&0&1\\
0&0&1   &1/2&0&-1/2\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
So, we conclude
$$
D^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{
-1/2&1&1/2\\
0&0&1\\
1/2&0&-1/2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

bla bla bla bla :
$$|{\rm D}|=2$$
blaaa blabla blabla:
$${\rm adj\; A}=\left[\begin{matrix}-1&2&1\\0&0&2\\1&0&-1\end{matrix}\right]$$
blah blehblaqa bla:
$${\rm A}^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}-1/2&1&1/2\\0&0&1\\1/2&0&-1/2\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Bla bla bla bla.  Bla bla, bla bla bla using Gauss bla bla, not bla bla adjugate blabla.